# TYPO3 tca suggest wizard for IRRE

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to add suggest wizard for type=inline in tca ?
I need the records to be created with inline interface. But I need an option to select previously created records too. Is that possible ?

For example I need suggest wizard for below tca code

```
'field_one' => array(
  'exclude' => 0,
  'label' => 'Label',
  'config' => array(
  'type' => 'inline',
  'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_name',
  'MM' => 'tx_myext_table_name_mm',
  'size' => 10,
  'autoSizeMax' => 30,
  'maxitems' => 5,
  'multiple' => 0,
 ),
),
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is unfortunately not possible but I would love to be wrong.

Comment: You can add a select field with add/edit wizards instead. Not as comfortable, but still an option.

Comment: Yes, initially it was select field with add/edit option. But client did not like that open in new page if click on add icon.